# Output Sorted KV Pcollection to a SST file from Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, rocksdb

I am trying to create a [SST file](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Creating-and-Ingesting-SST-files) from a Pcollection(Simple KV<String, String>>) using dataflow.This SST file will be later used for loading the rocksdb. However I see only limited built in IO support as [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/https://).

Is it possible to write to a different file format maintaining the order in dataflow?

Comment: This post could be vastly improved by telling us what you've tried so far in a minimal working example. E.g. provide us with an example of the Pcollection you want to output to an SST file (and how you've considered outputing it to an SST file).

Comment: Also, RocksDB has a Java interface RocksJava that may be useful for you. Though I don't know if it's well documented.

Comment: The Pcollection is a simple map of k-v sorted by key, and SST file produced is later used to load the rocksdb, I am still searching if its possible to do it before actually tying to implement using dataflow

Answer (score 0):

Beam does not have built in support for SST files.

You could use the [FileIO module](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d51a6012e22f34b9587a029fc8214915beea9fcb/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L150) to write such files but you need to develop a [Sink](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d51a6012e22f34b9587a029fc8214915beea9fcb/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L810) for this file format.

You could also write files from a simple ParDo transform, but you have to make sure that writing is correct and efficient (for example, make sure that you do not perform duplicate writes if a bundle fails and retried by the runner).

Comment: Hey @chamikara, I am trying to write a custom sink but the open method has input as [writableByteChannel](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L263), However the rocksdb sstfile writer takes in a filepath as [here](https://github.com/achristianson/nifi-minifi-cpp-ds/blob/master/thirdparty/rocksdb/java/src/main/java/org/rocksdb/SstFileWriter.java#L55), Any idea on how to solve this