# Google dataflow fails with JVM after 8 consecutive periods for Combine globally

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my pipeline I have around 4 million records and the flow is as follows

1. Read all records from bigquery
2. Transform to proto
3. Combine globally and create a sorted kv based SST file which is later used for Rocksdb

This pipeline works for records upto 1.5 million but later fails with this error.

> Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC
> thrashing. Memory is used/total/max = 2481/2492/2492 MB, GC last/max =
> 97.50/97.50 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=true. Heap dump not written.

The error doesn't change even I used several optimizations suggested in various other threads such as

1. Changing machine type to high memory
2. Decreasing the accumulators (reduced the worker count to 1)
3. Use ssd disk
4. --experiments=shuffle_mode=service

Current stats
[image]
I can't use a custom file sink as the underlying SST writer doesn't support writing from bytable channel as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72244923/output-sorted-kv-pcollection-to-a-sst-file-from-google-cloud-dataflow)

Any insight on resolving this would be helpful

Comment: Do you have a memory leak?

Comment: As in? The part where it fails is at the stage Combine-globally and Sort the kv pairs which i assume is very memory intensive. But even running with 1 worker with high memory having the same issue

Comment: Try connecting a profiler and look at memory usage.

Comment: How much data do you have in total? Will it all fit into memory at once?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that the Current memory is still 3.75 GB, upgrading the worker machine type to n1-standard-2 worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).